# Callback URL in Google App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm building an App Maker app that uses the Google OAuth2 library (https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2) to connect to an external service.

All is working fine until it comes to setting a callback URL. I've implemented the same type of project for a Google Sheets addon, but using apps script there I can get the script URL, but I can't seem to access that with App Maker, making it tricky to register the callback URL in the API I'm accessing.

Has anyone found a solution to this?

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know at least two ways how you can get callback URL:

1. Copy it from your deployment

[image]

2. Get it in runtime:

```javascript
// server script
var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
```